# How to set color for each value on array?

Tags: qt4

I am developing an application in QT, in which i am declaring an array of values and get the parse value in it. In which i have to set different colors for every individual values,

Here is the lines of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<n.count();i++)
 {
 QString Name = name[i];
 QString Tips = tips[i];
 QString City = city[i];
 QString Time = time[i];

 strList << Name + "\n" + City + "\n" + Tips + "\n" + Time;
 }
 ui->listWidgetmyprofile->addItems( strList );
```

I want to set individual colors for name, city, tips and time. 
Is there any coding or properties that is to be set for that??

Thanks in advance.
Naufal.A

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<n.count();i++)
{
 QString Name = name[i];
 QString Tips = tips[i];
 QString City = city[i];
 QString Time = time[i];
 strList << Name;
 strList << City;
 strList << Tips;
 strList << Time; 
}

ui->listWidgetmyprofile->addItems( strList );

for (int i=0; i<n.count();i++) {
  ui->listWidgetmyprofile->item(4*i)->setForeground(Qt::red);
  ui->listWidgetmyprofile->item(4*i+1)->setForeground(Qt::blue);
  ui->listWidgetmyprofile->item(4*i+2)->setForeground(Qt::black);
  ui->listWidgetmyprofile->item(4*i+3)->setForeground(Qt::yellow);
}
```

Comment: i had tried this coding but when i run this code, it get stopped at runtime and terminates. The problem i think at that this point "(4*i)" where we declare it. I am not setting the values in the array, i am getting it from parser,did u get me??

Comment: What error are you getting when your program stops at runtime ?

Comment: It has stopped working and does not open the application itself. I think there may be fault or error at this point (4*i)

Comment: What type of error is it throwing ? If these lines are throwing a problem, it means that the way the listWidgetmyprofile items have been defined may be wrong. Have you tried debugging line per line ? Is there an error log ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add comment yet, I add on @Mademoiselle Geek answer. There is array out of bound error.. The second for loop should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<n.count()/4;i++) {
```

See if this works.